# How can I search a PowerShell Get-Help entry?

Tags: powershell, grep, powershell-cmdlet, manpage

On Linux, I often use `grep` with context to find usage information in man pages. Something like

```
man ls | grep -e '-a' -A 5
```

will give me enough context to know what the `-a` option does.

I think `Select-String` can do something similar, but I can't seem to pipe in the *content* of `Get-Help`, just a `Get-Help` object. I'd like to do something like

```
Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Detailed | Select-String -Pattern "-Name" -Context 5
```

to get information about the `-Name` usage, but this doesn't seem to work.

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Lee said, if you want just the help for a parameter, use `Get-Help`'s `-Parameter` argument. Otherwise, you can use `Select-String` if you convert the output of `Get-Help` to an array of strings with `Out-String -Stream`.

```
Get-Help Get-ChildItem| Out-String -Stream | Select-String file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want help on the name parameter you can do:

`Get-Help Get-ChildItem -parameter Name`

Comment: This is very useful. Probably what I will use mostly from now on.